# Add dynamic class via variable to existing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't find a working solution to add a dynamic class to existing classes.

My example variable:

```
...
var num = Math.ceil(OtherVariable/100)*100;
...
```

I tried `attribute`:

```
$(this).attr('class', num)
```

Works, but kill my other classes in the same div.

I tried `addClass`:

```
$(this).addClass(num)
```

Doesn't work.

**The solution is:**

```
$(this).addClass(num.toString())
```

Big thx to "A. Wolff"!

Comment: .addClass(num) doesn't show any value, but at the same way $(this).attr('class', num) do ... I think its not possible to add classes by var and addClass if the var isn´t a fix value?

Comment: your $(this) may not be the valid / correct DOM which you want to add the class

Comment: You need to pass string, not number: `$(this).addClass(num.toString())`

Comment: @A.Wolff You are absolutly right - thats it!! Big thx!!